# chromium renamed after using youtube webapp

Tags: 13.10, chromium, webapps

Using Ubuntu 13.10. with Chrommium browser. 
After uninstalling the youtube webapp, my chromium was renamed to 'youtube' although it acts as a normal browser. Dash search for 'chromium' or 'youtube' both return the same icon - Chromium named 'Youtube'.
Also, right click context menu for the app says 'Youtube' instead of offering to open normal/incognito windows.

So far, I've been unsuccessful in finding the solution on my own or on the web.. Tried removing/purging/reinstalling both chromium and youtube webapp with restarts inbetween.

It's not a terrible issue since everything is basically working fine, but I'd like to know how to fix it anyways. It mostly just feels bad :)

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I would check ~/.local/share/applications to see if there is a chromium or YouTube desktop file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel stupid for answering my own question so soon but here it is..

It all went back to normal after removing the youtube webapp, chromium browser and chromium ppa and finally reinstalling  chromium after the reboot.

I tried reinstalling before, but it didn't work before manually changing the filename from Youtube to Chromium in ~/.local/share/applications

I still don't see why did that make any difference but thank you for pointing me to the right direction, saiarcot895.